# How to backup an application's database

Tags: bash, backup

I am trying to write a script to backup a database managed by an application, and want to know if there is a simpler way to do it. I think I'm making it way to complicated.

Basically I am stopping the application services (aside from the database) and save it into a text file, that is read until it gives the appropriate output. Then, I run a script that exports the database to two files, and writes the output to the another text file, that is read until it is successful. Then, I start the services again.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Make sure to run in the right folder!

echo "Here it will stop the manager services"

/etc/init.d/arcsight_services stop manager > /tmp/tmp/mangerstatusdown.txt

while [["./rr.sh /tmp/tmp/managerstatusdown.txt" != "[manager status down]"]]

do 

    echo "Not Ready Yet"
    read -p "Do you think it's ready to move on?"

done 

echo "Now it will export the database"

/opt/arcsight/manager/bin/arcsight export_system_tables > /tmp/tmp/systemtables.txt

while [["./rr.sh /tmp/tmp/systemtables.txt" != "[system tables export successful]" ]]
do 

    echo "Not Ready Yet"
    read -p "Do you think it's ready to move on?"

done

echo "Here it will start the manager again"

/etc/init.d/arcsight_services start manager
```

This is the rr.sh script that is referenced:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r line || [[ -n "$line"]]; do
    echo "Text read from file:  $line"
done < "$1"


#run as follows:
#chmod +x rr.sh
#./rr.sh filename.txt
```

This is actually my first script, so keep that in mind when you're explaining please!

Comment: cmds/options/strs etc inside of `[[ ]]` pairs need to be separated from the surrounding `[[ ]]` by spaces, so you'll need `read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do` for that line to work. In the future, learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` doesn't do string comparison directly; you need to use a specific command.

```
while [[ "$(./rr.sh /tmp/tmp/systemtables.txt)" != "[system tables export successful]" ]]
do
```